# Get one period only before a file extension

Tags: c#, url

I am trying to make a small program to read a URLs from a DB and attach them to SAP B1 Deliveries.

Example source URL : 
http://xxxx/xx/xxx/xxx/xxx/x/xxxx.pdf

Code:

```
oAttDelv.Lines.SourcePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(row.AttachURL);
oAttDelv.Lines.FileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(row.AttachURL);
oAttDelv.Lines.FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(row.AttachURL);                    
int iErr = oAttDelv.Add();

int AttEntry = 0;

int temp_int = lErrorCode;
string temp_string = sErrorMsg;
oCompany.GetLastError(out temp_int, out temp_string);
```

The error shown in temp_string is as in the image. How do I resolve the two periods before pdf and get just one?

Errors:

```
temp_int = -5002
temp_string = "Source file does not exist  , 'http:\\*****************\\jspui\\bitstream\\123456789\\2444\\1\\500393..pdf'"
```

Comment: use a string.replace?

Comment: Paste the textual stack trace instead of making an image of it.

Comment: Please add your explanations, error codes, etc to your question, instead of images.

Comment: Where is lErrorCode set?

Comment: Why is there 2 dots in first place?

Comment: SeM. That is what I am trying to resolve. Why the SourcePath FileName and FileExtension combination brings two dots.

Comment: @KinyanjuiKamau Probably when you get FileExtension, it comes with dot, try to `TrimStart('.')` (`oAttDelv.Lines.FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(row.AttachURL).TrimStart('.')`) before combining.

Comment: Yes, [GetExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netframework-4.7.2), return the extention with the dot.

Comment: I must say that an MCVE using a test string is not that hard, and will give a better view of the process of conbining the path.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var temp_string = @"Source file does not exist , 'http:\*****************\jspui\bitstream\123456789\2444\1\500393..pdf'";
var file_name = temp_string.Substring(temp_string.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1).Replace("..", ".");
```

Comment: this might solve the effect, but does not target any root cause

Comment: Tried that work around and it works. As royalTS puts it, there is an underlying cause for this. I just went a different route.